Auto-translation of laravel-vue-i18n does not work in the table from datatables.net
I have a project in Vue.js 3, Laravel, and it has a table made on datatables.net.
But the problem is that the table has attributes for auto-translation from laravel-vue-i18n, and for some reason they don’t work.
Can you tell me the reason.
Images my databases
Here is my code from a project where there is auto translation from laravel-vue-i18n, and a table datatables.net
Index.vue
<style>
</style>
<script setup>
    import { Head, Link,useForm } from '@inertiajs/vue3';
    import AdminLayout from '@/Pages/Admin/Components/AdminLayout.vue';
    import { trans } from "laravel-vue-i18n";
    import Checkbox from '@/Pages/Admin/Components/Checkbox.vue';
    import Filter from '@/Pages/Admin/Content/Brand/Filter.vue';

    import DangerButton from '@/Pages/Admin/Components/DangerButton.vue';
  
    import Pagination from '@/Pages/Admin/Components/Pagination.vue';

    import { usePage } from '@inertiajs/vue3'
    import { router } from '@inertiajs/vue3'

    import { ref } from 'vue';
    const props = defineProps({
        brands_count: {
            type: Number,
            brands:Object
        },
        
    });


    const brands = usePage().props.brands;
    const SelectBrand = ref(false);
    const SelectListBrands = ref([]);

    const SelectItembrand = () => {
        if(SelectBrand.value) {
            SelectListBrands.value = brands.map(brand => brand.id)
        } else {
            SelectListBrands.value = [];
        }
    
    }

    const onChecked = (id) => {
        
        const index = SelectListBrands.value.indexOf(id);
        if(index === -1) {
            SelectListBrands.value.push(id);
        } else {
            SelectListBrands.value.splice(index,1);
        }

    }


    const onDelete = (id) => {
        if(confirm(trans("you_delete_title"))){
            router.visit(route('admin.brand.delete'), {
                method: 'post',
                data: {
                    id: id

                },
            })
        }
    };
    const DeleteAllBrand = () => {
        if(confirm(trans("you_delete_title"))){
            router.visit(route('admin.brand.deleteAll'), {
                method: 'post',
                data: {
                    SelectListBrands: SelectListBrands.value

                },
            })
        }
    };

    const columns = [
        { data: 'id' },
        { data: 'name' },
        { data: 'is_active' },
        { data: 'created_at' },
    ];

</script>
<template>
    <AdminLayout>
        <Head :title="trans('brands')" />
        <div class="flex mb-5 justify-between ">
            <h1 class="font-semibold text-3xl text-gray-800 leading-tight"> {{ trans('brands') }} - {{ brands_count }}</h1>
            <div>
                <Link :href="route('admin.brand.create')" class="mr-3 bg-green_link rounded-lg hover:bg-green_link_hover text-white font-semibold py-3 px-4 border bg-green_link hover:border-transparent rounded">
                    <i class="fa-solid fa-plus"></i>
                    <span class="ml-2">{{trans("add_brand")}}</span>
                </Link>
                <DangerButton class="bg-red-500  text-white"  v-if="SelectListBrands.length>0" @click="DeleteAllBrand" >{{ trans('delete') }}</DangerButton>
       
            </div>
            
        </div>
        <!-- Filter of brand-->
        
        <Filter></Filter>
        
        <!-- -->

        <div class="relative overflow-x-auto shadow-md sm:rounded-lg">
            <DataTable
                :data="brands"
                :columns="columns"
                class="w-full text-sm text-left rtl:text-right text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400">
                <thead class="text-medium py-4 uppercase text-white bg-bg_black_admin dark:bg-gray-700 dark:text-gray-400">
                    <tr > 
                        <th scope="col" class="px-6 py-6">{{ trans('brands') }}</th>
                        <th scope="col" class="px-6 py-3">Name</th>
                        <th scope="col" class="px-6 py-3">Is active</th>
                        <th scope="col" class="px-6 py-3">Created</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
            </DataTable>
        </div>
        
    </AdminLayout>
    
</template>


does translation work outside of datatable?

Automatic translation works on all pages and blocks except the table.
